# Get Downloable product list array in .phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to display downloadable products on the customer account page.
I create one tab after the order tab on the customer account page.

**I want to get customer ordered product list in this page.**

I create a custom block and I wrote all queries and I want to get product collection and customer it inside the .phtml file.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface;
use Magento\Downloadable\Api\LinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
class CustomTabs extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

 
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $data;
    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;
 
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $_orderCollectionFactory;

    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer,
        LinkRepositoryInterface $linkRepository,
        CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
        )
    {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->linkRepository = $linkRepository;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }
    

    /**
     * Get list of links of Downloadable Product.
     *
     * 
     * @return LinkInterface[]
     */

    public function getCustomerData(){
       $data = [];
       $dataitem = [];
        $customer = $this->customer;
        $customerId = $customer->getId(); 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    
            
        $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
         foreach($orders as $order){
            $orderId = $order->getId(); 
            
            $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            $orderItemsCollection = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            
            foreach ($orderItemsCollection as $item){ 
               $productId = $item['product_id'];
              $productdata = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);

                    foreach($productdata as $product){
                        $sku = $product['sku'];
                           $data[] = $product['sku'];
                        $downloadableLink = $this->linkRepository->getList($sku);
                        foreach ($downloadableLink as $link ) {
                           //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($link->getData());
                              $data[] = $link->debug();

                             //$data[$key]["downloadablelinks"]= $link['id'];
                        }

                   } 
                 
                
            }         
         }

    return $data; 
}

}
```

I get the last foreach loop data but the way I get it's totally wrong. can someone please give the suggestion to how I can get it. the product collection and order collection in my .phtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to help a bit

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class Test
{
    public function getCustomerData()
    {
        $orders = []; // remove this line with your code

        /** @var Order $order */
        foreach($orders as $order) {
            /** @var Quote $quote */
            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());

            /** @var Item $item */
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $downloadableLink = $this->linkRepository->getList($item->getProduct()->getSku());
                foreach ($downloadableLink as $link) {
                    // do whatever you want to do here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The points in your code are as follows

You already have a order object here, you are doing stuff twice

```
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
```

You are not taking the correct approach to reach the product, The correct approach is as follows

```
OrderCollection >> Order >> Quote >> QuoteItem >> Product >> Product Attributes
```

You need to clean up your code, may be some articles here can help you out http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/articles.php

Comment: Thank you, Nadeem.